# How to efficiently run parallel processes in python, while each should read from a big file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, protocol-buffers

I have a large delimited protobuf file (can be between 1GB-30GB).
Each message in the file has a certain format, where the first attribute is a string, and the second is a repeated (list like) object that contains 2 attributes.

It's similar to this text representation

## BIG FILE:

```
first 10:32, 12:1, ... ,100002:3
second 1:3, 15:5, ... ,548756:57
...
...
ten_million 4:7, 48:4, ... ,12357458:8
```

Currently my code looks something like that:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool
from google.protobuf.internal.decoder import _DecodeVarint32
import proto_pb2


def read_message(buffer, n, message_type):
    message = message_type()
    msg_len, new_pos = _DecodeVarint32(buffer, n)
    n = new_pos
    msg_buf = buffer[n:n + msg_len]
    n += msg_len
    message.ParseFromString(msg_buf)
    return message


class A:
    def __init__(self, big_file):
        with open(big_file, 'rb') as fp:
            self.buf = fp.read()

    def get_line(self, n):
        return read_message(self.buf, n, proto_pb2.line_type)


def func(obj_a, lines):
    res = []
    for line in lines:
        res.append(obj_a.get_line(line))
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_lines = [[54487, 78, 10025, 548967], [12, 3218], [45786, 5744, 567, 45648], [45156, 456, 75]]
    a = A(big_file)
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(func, itertools.product([a], all_lines))
    print(result)
```

I open and read the file inside the class and hold it once creating a class object to avoid multiple openings/closings of the file.
It fits into the memory but I'd like to avoid that.

Then I expect each of the processes created by the Pool to read the lines it needs from the file and return the wanted result.
All the sub-processes will only read from the file (no writing) and print/return the results 
Currently it doesn't really works in parallel, seems to me that it waits on acquiring lock for a long time before each process can run.
I assume that it's happening due to the large size of the file, which being copied for each process.

What would be a proper implementation?

*This code is only used for the example, the actual file is a protobuf file (hope I haven't made many mistakes there), and I keep a mapping (dict) of the lines numbers and their location in the file*

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? ``self.buf = fp.read()`` will read the entire "1GB-30GB" into memory, at once; depending on your multiprocessing setup, that chunk may get copied for each subprocess. This tasks seems not to benefit from multiprocessing at all, quite the contrary.

Comment: into memory, at once, and **as a single chunk of text**, not divided in lines - where is the code for yout "return_line" funcition?

Comment: ANd the chunk _will_ be copied for each subprocess, as the "A" object is passed as a parameter for multiprocessing-  "obj_a.buf" is a Python string that is pickled duplicated in each process along with other instance data.

Comment: And of course, a several gigabyte sized text file is not the best data structure to read random text lines from. If it all fits in your memory, so make a list of strings, with each line in a string, as is usual in Python. But there are ways to make this truly efficient by creating a memory-mapped object and an index for the lines - or, simply using sqlite.

Comment: I've edited the question,
I'm trying to create an index object that will "serve" all the sub-processes. I have a delimited protobuf file which I need to read from (I get this file from outside).
My current implementation works on a single process, but now I have to scale up.
I figured that this is not the way to do it, but was hoping for a good suggestion.
I was thinking about switching to sqlite or something similar to that, but was hoping to find a good solution within python.

Comment: sqlite is within Python - we just needed  more details about how you actually split the lines and get to the data in this file - now - that you have  the "read_message" it seems worse - you actually scan the file for each line read with the `_DecodeVarint` call. Anyway, this is answerable now - hold on.

Comment: @jsbueno thanks, I'm going over pythons sqlite documentation, wasn't aware of that in python.
I might just use that, anyway it would be great to learn the right approach for it

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, will I be better in opening the file in each process? 
I have to start with a delimited protobuf file, but I can also do some pre-processing to it instead of working with it directly.
The file is actually an inverted index, which means that I'll need only a few random lines from it each time (for each query) and it'll be running with many queries. I'm not sure if SQLite is the right approach since I mainly need fast random access, don't really need all the functionality SQL has to offer